# How can I change text size and bold in asp:LinkButton?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have this asp control:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="X" runat="server" />
```

How can I change text size and bold to display the **X**  text similar to this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An asp:linkbutton renders as an < a > tag so write some CSS that targets that and styles it as you need to.

For example, if you gave it a class:

```
<asp:linkbutton cssclass="mybutton" runat="server" text="X"/>
```

You could style it

```
a.mybutton {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's from [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). If so, use the following instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server">
  <i class="fa fa-times fa-5x"></i>
</asp>
```